# How do I get the two energy capsules in the ceiling of Armored Armadillo's stage?

Tags: mega-man-x

During the first chase section of Armored Armadillo's stage there is a section with two energy capsules in the ceiling blocked off by rocks. How do you get these two energy capsules?

[image: energy capsules in the ceiling]

Answer (score 1):

You need an upgrade that based on your picture you are still missing. That will allow you to break some blocks by headbutting them, Mario style.

Coincidentally, that upgrade is also required to get the other upgrade you are missing. Yet, if you care for plot and cutscenes, I advise you keep a backup password before you get that last upgrade. You can safely beat all the eight bosses and unlock the final stages, just do not get the armor part that requires you to break the same kind of blocks in your original question.
Since that upgrade will actually be **required** later, the game has an interesting way to ensure you still get it if you miss the original version, far more interesting than just blocking your way like they did with the dash upgrade. Both ways to get this final part are equivalent in this game (some of the remakes actually change that, giving two different options) but it is still nice to play thru the alternate way at least once.

Comment: When should I be making a backup password? Is there a point of no return?

Comment: @Stevoisiak just before going to the final levels (so just after the usual 8 bosses,right when the final stages unlock in usual Megaman style) and without the arm cannon armor part